# Python TCP Recieving

Tags: python, encoding, tcp, decode

As I work farther into my program I have come across this issue that I cant seem to solve so here it goes. When I send Code to a box it sends a command back and then I decode it and I am able to do that. But the issue I am running into is when I get the response back with the hex code it seems to put it into brackets and every hex code gets put around quotation marks and its messing up how I am doing my program. Here is my code.

```
TX = b"\x7E\x00\x0C\x01\x00\xA5\xBD\x00\x7E\x01\x00\x40\x2D\x00\x3F\x71"

T_X = 'TX = '
R_X = 'RX = '

BUFFER = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
b = 1
while b == 1:
    s.send(TX)        
    time.sleep(1)

    __ByteStr2 = repr(s.recv(BUFFER))
    xString = __ByteStr2[2:-1]
    __bytStr = ByteToHex(xString)

    newString = __bytStr[48:-6]

    print (type(__ByteStr2))
    print (__bytStr)
    print (newString)
```

The main problem is that the code out puts like this.

```
['7E', '00', '16', '81', 'A5', 'BD', '35', '02', '7E', '00', '01', 'C7', '2D', '0A', '00', '11', '40', '12', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'F7', '0E']
```

The code should actually be outputting everything like this.

```
7E 00 16 81 A5 BD 35 02 7E 00 01 C7 2D 0A 00 11 40 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 F7 0E
```

I honestly dont know why it is doing that though.. any help would be awesome:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing strings with string-representations. Remove the `repr` around the `recv`.

You only need `repr` if you want to print out a string that contains "unprintable" characters. See the difference here:

```
>>> print "hello\nworld"
hello
world
>>> print repr("hello\nworld")
'hello\nworld'
```

So all the index-magic, byte-to-hex conversion etc. it unneccessary.

Additionally, you are doing networking wrong. `recv` is not guaranteed to receive all data you expect it to, so you need to follow a protocol. You don't say what the "box" is - if it's your own doing, I suggest using zeromq or nanomsg instead. If it's a 3rd-party-thing, the documentation should contain hints.

Comment: Thank :) That seemed to fix it